# How to refresh RecyclerView with SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I use [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) to group items in a RecyclerView.
After add new partitions and/or add an item to a section I call notifyDataSetChanged but the list is not refreshed.

```
MyRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The data definitely change because after turning the screen rotation list is updated.

Comment: is the method "getAdapter()" called from an instance? or is a static method? I'm asking because you write it with uppercase "MyReciclerView"

Comment: MyRecyclerView is an instance, not a static method.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with the code of your Section class?

Comment: @Arvalon  how did you resolved the issue ? I am also facing the same issue